# Need to mute audio and change image with JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am trying to create a toggle switch for the audio that replaces the icon dependent on the state. Here is my code (that is not working):

```
<div id="bgAudioControls">

<a href="#" onclick="muteSound()">
<img id="mute" src="img/sound-off.svg" width="64" height="64" alt="Sound Off" />
</a>

<audio id="bgAudio" autoplay loop preload src="ogg/epic-lead.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</div>


<script language="javascript">
    function muteSound() {

    if (document.getElementById("mute").src == "img/sound-off.svg")
    {
        document.getElementById("unmute").src = "img/sound-on.svg";
        document.getElementById('bgAudio').muted = true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("mute").src = "img/sound-off.svg";
        document.getElementById('bgAudio').muted = false;
    }
    }
    </script>
```

I am positive I am overlooking something SUPER simple.. Any help appreciated.

A live view of the whole code in action can be seen at http://arc.adamroper.com

---

The below code works - albeit as two buttons, not a toggle.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('bgAudio').muted = true;">Mute</a>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('bgAudio').muted = false;">Unmute</a>
```

Comment: Or, use a JS variable to remember the mute state and toggle the audio accordingly, don't rely on some DOM attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** : working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fX7z3/9/)

What says @Stasik is :

You have to remove `id="mute"` from the `<a>` tag and put it in the `<img>` tag

Like this:

```
<a href="#"  onclick="muteSound()"><img id="mute" src="img/sound-off.svg" /></a>
```

**UPDATE**

to play/pause try this found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721795/play-and-pause-one-html5-audio-element-at-a-time-via-jquery)

**COMPLETE CODE**

HTML

```
<div id="bgAudioControls">
    <a href="#" >
        <img id="mute" src="img/sound-off.svg" width="64" height="64" alt="Sound Off" />
    </a>

    <audio id="bgAudio" autoplay loop preload src="ogg/epic-lead.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    $("#mute").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var song = $('audio')[0]
        if (song.paused){
            song.play();
            document.getElementById("mute").src = "img/sound-on.svg";
        }else{
            song.pause();
            document.getElementById("mute").src = "img/sound-off.svg";
        }
        });
});
```

Comment: I have done that, but how does that allow me to switch icons and audio by clicking on the one image?

A quick example is here: http://arc.adamroper.com

I want to click the speaker icon, which will mute the audio and change the icon. then, clicking again will unmute and change the icon back.

Comment: I can get it to mute/unmute - but only as two different buttons.
I want to change the icon and mute status with a single onClick event.

Comment: Are you working on the link you provided ? this one : http://arc.adamroper.com/ I don't see no change on the source..

Comment: I am working on my local webserver. I just uploaded the version I am fiddling with. ie; trying to get the two buttons to work as a single toggle.

Comment: I have just added the onclick event to the image - for now.

Comment: This code does **HALF** of what I want..
    
`<img id="mute" src="img/sound-off.svg" width="64" height="64" alt="Sound Off" onclick="document.getElementById('bgAudio').muted = true;document.getElementById('mute').src = 'img/sound-on.svg';" style="cursor:pointer;" />`

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly! :)
Thank you! :p
I have been staring at this for far too long! :)

Comment: Your page is working I just checked it 30 sec ago :) Please Don't forget to make my answer as Accepted :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Accessing ".src" of the mute element is not correct, since src is the attribute of the  child of the mute element. Assign id="mute" to the  element directly for a quick fix.

Comment: I just updated the code above. The page can be viewed at http://arc.adamroper.com