# How to pause the audio and play the clicked audio

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am creating a music player, I can play the audio when an album is clicked but when another album is clicked both songs play simultaneously, I need to pause the previous song and play the new song. I have written the code in such a way that I need to get the inner text of the clicked album and then play the song.

I have 27 album div tags, If we click on one album div this code will take the inner HTML and play the song of that name, if we click another album div, it will take the inner HTML and play the song along with the already playing song, I just need to pause the old song and play the new song

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
// PLAY MUSIC OF CLICKED ALBUM
for (var i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".album")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

    //getting inner text of clicked album
    let songName = this.querySelector("div.album > h4").innerText;

    //playing song of the album clicked
    let playThisSong = "assets/songs/" + songName + ".mp3";
    let playSong = new Audio(playThisSong);
    playSong.play();
   
    //need code to pause previous audio and play the clicked album audio

  });
}
```

Here is the required HTML code:

```
    <div class="albums-container">
                <div class="album">
                    <img src="./assets/images/Dooriyan.jpg" alt="dooriyan-logo">
                    <h4>Dooriyan</h4>
                    <img class="play-btn" src="./assets/images/play-btn.png" alt="playBtn">
                </div>
                <div class="album">
                    <img src="./assets/images/Zara Zara.jpg" alt="dooriyan-logo">
                    <h4>Zara Zara</h4>
                    <img class="play-btn" src="./assets/images/play-btn.png" alt="playBtn">
                </div>
                <div class="album">
                    <img src="./assets/images/Tu Aake Dekhle.jpg" alt="dooriyan-logo">
                    <h4>Tu Aake Dekhle</h4>
                    <img class="play-btn" src="./assets/images/play-btn.png" alt="playBtn">
                </div>
    </div>
```

The solution can be:
Remove query selector all or for loop and use another method, or use if-else to play and pause. Or something else.

Comment: Perhaps also include the related HTML (put the HTML and JavaScript in a functioning snippet?) so we can best assist you.

Comment: FWIW your selectors are only selecting ONE with `document.querySelector(` 0- and you are adding new event listeners inside an event listener - a bad idea that is part of your issue.

Comment: Store a variable OUTISDE of your query selector function for the last song that has been played. Then, every time you start playing a new song, first pause the old song.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play and pause one HTML5 audio element at a time via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721795/play-and-pause-one-html5-audio-element-at-a-time-via-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to create a new answer since you updated your code.

Store a variable OUTISDE of your query selector function for the last song that has been played. Then, every time you start playing a new song, first pause the old song.

```js
let lastPlayedSong = null;
// PLAY MUSIC OF CLICKED ALBUM
for (var i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".album")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

    //getting inner text of clicked album
    let songName = this.querySelector("div.album > h4").innerText;

    //playing song of the album clicked
    let playThisSong = "assets/songs/" + songName + ".mp3";
    let playSong = new Audio(playThisSong);
    playSong.play();
    //need code to pause previous audio and play the clicked album audio
    if (lastPlayedSong) lastPlayedSong.pause();
    lastPlayedSong = playSong;
          
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to illustrate my comment I left above. Here's the comment:

Store a variable OUTISDE of your query selector function for the last song that has been played. Then, every time you start playing a new song, first pause the old song.

```js
let currentlyPlaying = null;

// PLAY MUSIC OF CLICKED ALBUM
for (var i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".album")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

    //getting innner text of clicked album
    let songName = this.querySelector("div.album > h4").innerText;

    //playing song of the album clicked
    let playThisSong = "assets/songs/" + songName + ".mp3";
    let playSong = new Audio(playThisSong);
    playSong.play();

    //selecting the music player name and image and replacing with the selected album name and img
    let musicPlayerText1 = document.querySelector(".music-name strong");
    let musicPlayerText2 = document.querySelector(".music-name small");
    musicPlayerText1.innerHTML = songName;
    musicPlayerText2.innerHTML = songName;
    let changeImg = "assets/images/" + songName + ".jpg";
    document.querySelector(".music-icon img").src = changeImg;

    //hiding the play btn and showing the pause btn
    document.querySelector(".red-play-btn").style.display = "none"
    document.querySelector(".red-pause-btn").style.display = "block"

    //adding the play and pause audio function on click of play and pause btn
    document.querySelector(".red-pause-btn").addEventListener("click", function pauseAudio() {
      playSong.pause();
      document.querySelector(".red-pause-btn").style.display = "none"
      document.querySelector(".red-play-btn").style.display = "block"
    })
    document.querySelector(".red-play-btn").addEventListener("click", function playAudio() {
      if (currentlyPlaying) currentlyPlaying.pause();
      playSong.play();
      currentlyPlaying = playSong;
      document.querySelector(".red-play-btn").style.display = "none"
      document.querySelector(".red-pause-btn").style.display = "block"
    })

    //pause previous audio and play the clicked album audio


  });
}
```

Every line in the above code that includes the variable `currentlyPlaying` is an edit I've made to your code.

I think I've made some incorrect assumptions in how I handled it, but I think you can use the idea yourself, with your correct assumptions, and fix my broken code.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but my code is a little different, I took the inner HTML of the selected album, so I had to use the querySelectorAll, so I think that is making an issue here, I have made changes to the question, I would request you to have a quick look.

Comment: @MdFaiz the idea should be the same: store a variable outside of your loop for *the last song you pressed play on*, and call `.pause` on that variable the next time `play` is pressed on another one.

Answer (score -1):

```
//<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

// first include jquery then use below script
//You can use with jquery like below code and working fine
jQuery('.album').click(function() {
     let songName = jQuery(this).parents(".album").find("h4").text();
     //playing song of the album clicked
     let playThisSong = "assets/songs/" + songName + ".mp3";
     let playSong = new Audio(playThisSong);
     playSong.pause(); // First pause all other music then play this one
     playSong.play();
});
```